# Best practice for class used as functions collection with shared data

Tags: python, class

I have a code that gets some dirty data as input, then parse them, clean them, munge them, etc and then should return a value.

At the moment I structured it as a class where the `__init__` method receives the input and calls the other methods in a giving sequence. 
My class at the moment looks something like this:

```
class myProcedure:
    def __init__(self, dirty_data, file_name):

        self.variable1, self.variable2 = self.clean_data(dirty_data)
        self.variable3                 = self.get_data_from_file(file_name)

        self.do_something()

    def clean_data(self, dirty_data):
        #clean the data
        return variable1, variable2

    def get_data_from_file(self, file_name):
        #load some data
        return loaded_data

    def do_something(self):
        #the interesting part goes here
        self.result = the_result
```

Using a class instead of sparse functions allows to share data more easily. In my real code I have few tens of variable that get shared. The alternative would be to put them all in a dict or having each function to take 10-20 inputs. I find both this solutions a bit **cumbersome**

At the moment I must call it as:

```
useless_class_obj = myProcedure(dirty_data, file_name)
interesting_stuff = useless_class_obj.result
```

My concerns come form the fact that, once run, `useless_class_obj` does not have any purpose anymore and is just a useless piece of junk.

I think it would be more elegant to be able to use the class as:

```
interesting_stuff = myProcedure(dirty_data, file_name)
```

however this would require `__init__` to return something different than self.

Is there a better way to do this?
Am I doing this in a bad or hard-to-read way?

Comment: I'm asking myself if there is a better way to do this. If the best way is this one, creating the obj, then I don't mind too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... you could also do...

```
interesting_stuff = myProcedure(dirty_data, file_name).result
```

Comment: Ok. So this is just my mental masturbation? :P